# Firefox Breakpoints change submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox

I have an ajax call that sets a flag that can prevent submition.
The thing is, if I set the breakpoints on the `if(flag==1)` and `return true` statements and step through the code, it does redirect on flag =1 ...BUT if I dont, it never rediercts.
Whats going on?

```
$("#login").submit(function(e) {

var flag = 2;
var un  = $('#username').val();       
    $.ajax(
    {              
        type: "POST",
        url: "Utilities/CheckUsername.php",
        data: "un="+ un,
        success: function(data)
        {

            if(data=="Username Does Not Exist")
            {          

                flag=1;                      
            }
            else
            {
                $('#mike').html(data);
                flag=2;
            }                   
        }

    });
    if(flag==1)
         {
          return true;   
         }
         else
         {
          e.preventDefault();  
         } 
    return false;
     });

     });
```

EDIT:This still doesnt work . Just to clarify if the username does not exist we will move on to the register page, it not tell them the username is taken and try another.

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#submitButton").click(function(e) {
        var un  = $('#username').val();       
            $.ajax(
            {              
                type: "POST",
                url: "Utilities/CheckUsername.php",
                data: "un="+ un,
                success: function(data)
                {

                    if(data=="Username Does Not Exist")
                    {          
                       $('#login').submit();                   
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#mike').html(data);


                    }                   
                }

            });
             });

             }); 
             </script>
</head>
<body>
      <form name="login" id="login" method="post" action="dsds.html">
        UserName<input type="text" name="username" id="username"value="">
        <br/>
        Password<input type="text" name="password" id="password" value="">
        <br/>
        Password Again<input type="text" name="passwordagain" id="passwordagain" value="">
        <br/>
        <input type="hidden" name="NewClass" id="NewClass" value="true">
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submitButton" value="submit">
     </form>
     <span id = "mike"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you assume that $.ajax is a synchronous function, which it isn't. It doesn't wait for the ajax call to be finished before it advances to the next statement. This means, depending on the runtime of your ajax call, your flag variable might be set or not. In fact it will almost certainly not be set to anything else than 2 because the roundtrip for the ajax call will be longer than the time the JS executor needs to advance to your if-statement.

When you set a breakpoint at the if(flag==1) execution will stop there and ajax call has time to finish, which is why it works when you set a breakpoint but doesn't work when you don't have a breakpoint. I suggest modifying your code to something like:

```
$("#loginButton").click(function(e) {

var un  = $('#username').val();       
    $.ajax(
    {              
        type: "POST",
        url: "Utilities/CheckUsername.php",
        data: "un="+ un,
        success: function(data)
        {

            if(data=="Username Does Not Exist")
            {          

                // code for handling an error;                      
            }
            else
            {

                $('#mike').html(data);
                $('#loginForm').submit();

            }                   
        }

    });
```

});

When clicking the login button, your ajax call will perform the username check and finally submit the form itself, when the check is ok.